# Selecting the lines in a text file starting with integer values in java

Tags: java, pdf, text, file-io, pdfbox

### I have scraped a file from pdf using pdfbox for java and the output is as follows:

```
Tribhuvan University

Institute of Engineering

Entrance Examination Board

BE/BArch Entrance Examination 2070

Pass List

ROLLNO NAME GENDER DISTRICT Percent Rank

1001 AADARSH        DEO MALE Saptari 51.429 3442

1002 AADARSH        MALLA MALE Bajhang 43.429 5714

1003 AADARSHA        KHANAL MALE Rupandehi 40.571 6709
```

The list goes on with the repetition of first 6 lines in every page[150 pages]. What I need to do is to select the lines that starts with the integer value in java and create a new file with the list that starts with the integer value.

Comment: And you haven't attempted anything yet?!

Comment: I tried to delete the strings, however had  a problem with the page numbers as it goes from 1 to 150 and i need to preserve the numbers too.

Comment: Where is that code, which you've attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the output into separate lines and then use .startsWith("[0-9]") for each line.

For example:

```
// let's presume that you've loaded the lines into "List<String> lines"..

// empty ArrayList for storing the selected lines
List<String> linesToWrite = new ArrayList<>();

for(String line : lines)
{
    if(line.startsWith("[0-9]"))
    {
        linesToWrite.add(line);
    }
}
// and now write it to the other file
```

Comment: the startsWith("[0-9]") is not working however it works fine with character values.??

Comment: try using startsWith("[\d]") it's the same thing basically

Comment: what output are you getting in the second file? have you tried debugging it and watching what gets into "lines" and "linesToWrite"?

Comment: The problem is with the range[0-9], the output is fine if single integers are stated as line.startsWith("1");
[\d] didn't work too

Comment: well everything you have to check is the first char of the line, if I understood you correctly.. if it's a digit it should return true.. both "1asdqwe" and "12asd23asd" should be considered as a line starting with a digit..